# useSelector destructuring with union types?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

Recently I've tried to rethink a state structure I use in my application, but I came across some difficulties and not sure how to proceed with it.

At first I used the followign state structure for redux:

```
type State = {
  loading: boolean
  loaded: boolean
  items: Array<Item>
  categories: Array<Category>
}

const initialState: State = {
  loading: false,
  loaded: false,
  items: [],
  categories: [],
}
```

Its simple and easy to use with selectors, and because the type of `items` and `categories` stays alway the same, there is no need to worry about getting undefined or casting type. But I needed to add some extra properties that I need just a handful of times and desicded to create a seperate type for each redux action and now I have this:

```
type RequestItems = {
  category: Category;
  items: Array<Item>;
  totalCountFromServer: number;
}

export type RequestItem = {
  item: Item;
}

export type RequestCategories = {
  categories: Array<Category>
}

type RequestContent =
  | RequestItem
  | RequestItems
  | RequestCategories

type State = {
  loading: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
  content: RequestContent | undefined
}
```

This structure is less redundant, but I'm not sure if it is possible for useSelector to detremine extact type, or is there a better way to use it than this:

I think using state hooks here is a bit redundant here, but I can check for content slide being 'underfined' and return '404' if it is.

```
const { content, loading, loaded } = useSelector(state => ({
    content: state.suply.content,
    loading: state.suply.loading,
    loaded: state.suply.loaded,
  }))

  const [items, setItems] = useState<Items[]>([])
  const [category, setCategory] = useState<Category>(Category.emptyObject)
  const [totalCountFromServer, setTotalCountFromServer] = useState<number>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (content) {
      setItems((content as RequestItems).items)
      setCategory((content as RequestItems).category)
      setTotalCountFromServer((content as RequestItems).totalCountFromServer)
    }
  }, [content])
```

or this one; Here I get TypeError as the selector cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items', 'category', 'totalCountFromServer')

```
  const { content, loading, loaded } = useSelector(state => ({
    items: (state.suply.content as RequestItems).items,
    category: (state.suply.content as RequestItems).category,
    totalCountFromServer: (state.suply.content as RequestItems).totalCountFromServer,
    loading: state.suply.loading,
    loaded: state.suply.loaded,
  }))
```

or just use destructuring like this. it's working fine, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072200/useselector-destructuring-vs-multiple-calls) that using destructing with selector is the wrong approach

```
  const { content, loading, loaded } = useSelector(state => ({
    content: state.suply.content,
    loading: state.suply.loading,
    loaded: state.suply.loaded,
  }))

  const {items, category, totalCountFromServer } = (content as RequestItems);
```

So is there a better way to approach this using state with Union Type content, or I'm better off using my original structure?

Comment: There is no `suply` state slice in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Define Typed Hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks) doc. Create typed versions of the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks.

And use [Discriminating Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

E.g.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";

type Category = any;
type Item = any;

type RequestItems = {
  kind: "RequestItems";
  category: Category;
  items: Array<Item>;
  totalCountFromServer: number;
};

type RequestItem = {
  kind: "RequestItem";
  item: Item;
};

type RequestCategories = {
  kind: "RequestCategories";
  categories: Array<Category>;
};

type RequestContent = RequestItem | RequestItems | RequestCategories;

type State = {
  loading: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
  content: RequestContent | undefined;
};

const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<State> = useSelector;

const useHook = () => {
  const { content, loading, loaded } = useAppSelector((state) => ({
    content: state.content,
    loading: state.loading,
    loaded: state.loaded
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (content?.kind === "RequestItems") {
      // content is RequestItems
    }
  }, [content]);
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76431870-4lgyu4?file=/index.ts)

Comment: thanks, what about, how to use it? Should I use destructuring method or use state hook?

Comment: @Katherine Use `useAppSelector` hook, the `useHook` in my answer is an example

Comment: no, I get the useSelector, I'm already using a typed one for AppState `const useSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<AppState> = (selector, equalityFn = shallowEqual) =>
  useReduxSelector(selector, equalityFn)` but I'm looking for a way to use it where I don't need to cast `content` to a specific type, (i.e. `content: state.content as RequestItems`